# JQuery onchange for multiple elements but trigger only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have many select boxes in an HTML page and I have used the same class name '**paperGSM**' for all select elements and a function which triggers on change of the select box elements value.

```
var getPaperTypeFromGSM = function()
{
    $('div').off().on('change', '.paperGSM', function ()
    {
        console.log($(this).val());
        var url = 'api/getPaperTypeFromGSM';
        var postData = {
            paperGSM: $(this).val()
        };
        var $current = $(this);
        $.post(url, postData, function (result)
        {
            if (result.result == 1) {
                var output = "";
                output += '<option value="0">Select Paper Type</option>';
                for (var i = 0; i <result.paperType.length; i++) {
                    output += '<option value="' + result.paperType[i].paper_type_id + '">' + result.paperType[i].paper_type_name + '</option>';
                }
                $current.siblings('.paperType').prop("disabled", false).html(output);
                getPaperSizeFromPaperType();
            } else {
                Result.error(result);
            }
        }, 'json');
    });
    return false;
};
```

Every time the change event occurs it triggers multiple times (maybe it triggers for all the elements with the same class name). The image below explains the situation.

P.S: My logic and even the post function are working fine

As I do not want to hardcode the events for all elements (like give all elements different class name and hardcode the functions for all), **I only want one function working for all the same class elements but trigger it only once.**

If I ignore the multiple triggers everything is working fine it's just that, that thing is bothering me a lot.

[image]

Comment: I'd bet it's because onChange is fired every time you click a button. Typing 12345 triggers 5 onChange events

Comment: I think the reason is due to `eventBubbling`. To stop try this  `$('div').off().on('change', '.paperGSM', function (event){ event.stopPropagation(); // and rest of your codes..`

Comment: hey @The_ehT, that thing worked but the event does not trigger for the next select boxes. As I want a single function for multiple select boxes but it should trigger only once.

Comment: remove `.off()` from `div`.

Comment: When and where do you call `getPaperTypeFromGSM()`?

Comment: try using one click.. also use $(document).one("event","selector", callback) so that it will be usefull for all future elements also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is due to `eventBubbling`. To stop try this

```
$('div').on('change', '.paperGSM', function (event){ 
event.stopPropagation(); 
// ...and rest of your codes..
}
```

NB: Remove the `.off` as it will remove listener once this event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs this,
I found a workaround this by using `onchange event` and JQuery:

```
// The input:
<input class="jscolor" onchange="set_boxes_color(this.jscolor)" value="cc66ff">

// The function:
function set_boxes_color(picker) {
    var elements = $(".p_box");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.backgroundColor = '#' + picker;
    }
}
```

This will change the background color for all elements with class `p_box`